# Complete Source of a File & the File History from the remote

Tags: git

The following command will give the diff view of a given file:

```
gitk client/gwt/com/mycom/tradepage/MyEditWindow.java
```

Can anybody tell if it is possible to get the complete source (not just the diff) of a given file at a particular date (back in time). If it is possible, please specify the command that would do.

Got one more question:
The above gitk command shows the history of the file only from the local repository, is there a way to check the history of a given file from the remote, would be great at least if I can check the last commit date of a given file from the remote.

Answer (score 0):

To checkout the entire source for a file at a particular commit, you can use the following:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <filePath>
```

To view the history of a file from a particular remote, you should first fetch the latest history from the remote with the following:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

Then you can specify that you want to view the remote history of a file with the following:

```
git log <remoteBranch> -- <filePath>
```

So, for example, if you want to view the history of file `X` on your remote branch `origin/new-feature`, then you would use

```
git fetch origin
git log origin/new-feature -- X
```

You can read more about these usages of the [`checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), [`fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), and [`log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) commands at the [official Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs).

Comment: I think `git show <commit>:<filePath>` is what giri_col is looking for instead of git checkout.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci I like [`show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), it works really well and is probably better than using `checkout`, but you can still use `checkout` to find out the same thing though, can't you?

Comment: checkout would clobber any uncommitted changes to the file.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci, thanks a lot, git show <commit>:<filePath> is what I am looking for. I executed the same command with the following addition: git show <commit>:<filePath> > /c/new/mytempfile.java